# How can I convert this code to C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert this `VB` code to `C#`.

```
    If Right(Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(hNumb).Style), 6) = "NoNumb" Then
h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix")
SetDocVar "TablePrefix", "Table " & h_prefix & "."
t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix")
hNumb = "-"
Else
h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix")
SetDocVar "TablePrefix", "Table " & h_prefix & "."
t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix")
End If
```

I have tried below code,

```
if (Strings.Right(Strings.Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(hNumb).Style), 6) == "NoNumb") {  
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");  
    SetDocVar("TablePrefix", "Table " + h_prefix + ".");  
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");  
    hNumb = "-";  
} else {  
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");  
    SetDocVar("TablePrefix", "Table " + h_prefix + ".");  
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");  
}
```

> But, now I am getting error in `Strings.Right`, `Strings.Trim` and
>   `Paragraph[hNumb].Style`. Here style property not there. These three
>   place error is coming.

Please help me...

Comment: What errors you get? Have you referenced the microsoft.visualbasic dll because those methods aren't .NET but VB methods. I guess that `Paragraphs` is a collection like an array or list, then the C# indexer uses `[]` instead of `()`.

Comment: Use online code converter [Link](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)

Comment: @JayPatel I am pretty sure he already used some converter, because if he actually typed that C# Code he would have noticed that there is no ``Strings.Right`` method he can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
var style = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs[hNumb].Style;
var styleString = style.ToString().Trim();
if (styleString.Length >= 6 && styleString.Substring(style.Length - 6) == "NoNumb") 
{
    //rest of your code
```

I cannot try this code because I don't have that libraries you're using, but this should give you an idea how to convert that code..

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sir, now getting this error: `System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Trim`. Inside if condition it is not going.In Immediate window i checked its is showing value as "object"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
if ((ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(hNumb).Style.Trim().Substring((ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(hNumb).Style.Trim().Length - 6)) == "NoNumb")) {
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");
    SetDocVar;
    "TablePrefix";
    ("Table " 
                + (h_prefix + "."));
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");
    hNumb = "-";
}
else {
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");
    SetDocVar;
    "TablePrefix";
    ("Table " 
                + (h_prefix + "."));
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
string bookMark = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(hNumb).Style.ToString();
if (bookMark.Trim() == "NoNumb") {  
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");  
    SetDocVar("TablePrefix", "Table " + h_prefix + ".");  
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");  
    hNumb = "-";  
} else {  
    h_prefix = sGetDocVar("CTDPrefix");  
    SetDocVar("TablePrefix", "Table " + h_prefix + ".");  
    t_prefix = sGetDocVar("TablePrefix");  
}
```

Comment: Sir, now getting this error: `System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Trim`. Inside if condition it is not going.In Immediate window i checked its is showing value as "object" how I solve this?

Comment: Looks like VB was automatically performing a ToString() while c# was not.   Fixed code.